# facebook making stream more like feed (page-id/feed)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Now, i'm requesting this query:

```
$fb->api( array('method' => 'fql.query', 
   'query' => "SELECT [fields] FROM stream 
               WHERE source_id IN (
                     SELECT page_id 
                     FROM page 
                     WHERE page_id='415533455147213'
               ) AND type != '46' AND type != '' LIMIT 5"));
```

With `$fb->api('/415533455147213/feed?limit=3');` I was getting an picture(if a photo was aploaded, or shared), feeds author photo icon and photo caption... How to get those with FQL query properly?

Comment: Did you look at the ['stream' FQL table documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)? are the attachments to the post accessible in the `attachments` field?

Comment: How I didn't thought about that ... Thanks, this is just what I need :D

Comment: @BenasRadzevicius It would be nice if you could update your question by adding the same as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that all I need is hiding in the attachment column of the stream table ;]] as @Igy suggested ;]